# How do I get a value from XML column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

So, I have a table with a large chunk of data stored in XML.

The partial XML schema (down to where I need) looks like this:

```
<DecisionData>
  <Customer>
    <SalesAttemptNumber />
    <SubLenderID>IN101_CNAC</SubLenderID>
    <DecisionType>Decision</DecisionType>
    <DealerID />
    <CustomerNumber>468195994772076</CustomerNumber>
    <CustomerId />
    <ApplicationType>Personal</ApplicationType>
    <ApplicationDate>9/16/2008 11:32:07 AM</ApplicationDate>
    <Applicants>
      <Applicant PersonType="Applicant">
        <CustNum />
        <CustomerSSN>999999999</CustomerSSN>
        <CustLastName>BRAND</CustLastName>
        <CustFirstName>ELIZABETH</CustFirstName>
        <CustMiddleName />
        <NumberOfDependants>0</NumberOfDependants>
        <MaritalStatus>Single</MaritalStatus>
        <DateOfBirth>1/1/1911</DateOfBirth>
        <MilitaryRank />
        <CurrentAddress>
          <ZipCode>46617</ZipCode>
```

Unfortunately, I am unfamiliar with pulling from XML, and my google-fu has failed me.

```
 select TransformedXML.value('(/DecisionData/Customer/Applicants/Applicant PersonType="Applicant"/CurrentAddress/ZipCode/node())[1]','nvarchar(max)') as zip
from XmlDecisionInputText as t
```

I believe my problem lies with the portion that goes Applicant PersonType="Applicant", but am unsure how to deal with it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath in its simplest form would be:

```
TransformedXML.value('(//ZipCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS zip
```

This will find the first ZipCode node anywhere inside your document. If there are multiple, just be specific (as much as you want but not any more):

```
TransformedXML.value('(/DecisionData/Customer/Applicants/Applicant[@PersonType="Applicant"]/CurrentAddress/ZipCode)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') AS zip
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=93de1f74af18157bd8476b84c23b346f)

Comment: Thanks!  This got me what I needed.  It appears I was missing the square brackets, which I didn't know I'd need.

Comment: That is called attribute selector.

Answer (score 0):

If there are MULTIPLE applicants, you can use a CROSS APPLY

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  XmlDecisionInputText A
 Cross Apply (
    Select PersonType    = x.v.value('@PersonType','VARCHAR(150)')
          ,CustLastName  = x.v.value('CustLastName[1]','VARCHAR(150)')
          ,CustFirstName = x.v.value('CustFirstName[1]','VARCHAR(150)')
          ,ZipCode       = x.v.value('CurrentAddress[1]/ZipCode[1]','VARCHAR(150)')
     From  XmlDecisionInputText.nodes('DecisionData/Customer/Applicants/*') x(v)
             ) B
```

Comment: I see where you are headed.  But I can't transform your use of an XML variable  in the from clause to an XML column (TransformedXML) in a table (XmlDecisionInputText)